# CompletableFuture in Java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, completable-future

I have this piece of code that I wanted to refactor to Java 8

```
List<String> menus = new ArrayList<String>();           
for (Menu menu : resto1.getMenu()) {            
    MainIngredient mainIngredient = MainIngredient.getMainIngredient(menu.getName());           
    if (mainIngredient.getIngredient().indexOf("Vegan")!=-1) {
        menus.add(menu.getName());
    }                   
}
```

After refactoring this simple loop it seems like too much code... am I using CompletableFutures correctly?

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List<CompletableFuture<MainIngredient>> priceFutureList = resto1.getMenu().stream()
    .map(menu -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        () -> MainIngredient.getMainIngredient(menu.getName()), executorService))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());        

CompletableFuture<Void> allFuturesDone = CompletableFuture.allOf(
    priceFutureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[priceFutureList.size()]));

CompletableFuture<List<MainIngredient>> priceListFuture =        
    allFuturesDone.thenApply(v -> priceFutureList.stream()
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .collect(toList()));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just?

```
List<String> menus = resto1.getMenu()
                           .stream()
                           .map(m -> MainIngredient.getMainIngredient(m.getName()))
                           .filter(m -> m.getIngredient().indexOf("Vegan")!=-1)
                           .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

is your imperative approach really slow that you have to use `CompletableFuture`?

Comment: "is your imperative approach really slow that you have to use CompletableFuture" Depends if the execution needs to be lazy. Seems like the answer should be no as the original execution is upfront.

Comment: @flakes Agreed. had to leave that question there as I think the OP is getting confused/heading the wrong way to some extent anyway...

Comment: Yeah. Also if lazy execution is required, the OP could just return the raw `Stream` instead of collecting it.